# cython poor performance with C++ STL

Tags: stl, cython

I want to speed up my program with openmp, so I need to change the Python class to a C++ class. However, C++ classes run very slowly:
Python class code:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,lind,pxlmean,pxlstd,pxlcnt,bandcnt):
        #(2,n)
        self.lind=lind
        self.pxlmean=pxlmean
        self.pxlstd=pxlstd
        self.pxlcnt=pxlcnt
        self.bandcnt=bandcnt
import numpy as np
def pcreateobj(num):
    lst=[]
    for i in range(num):
        lst.append(Obj({0:range(1000)}, range(1000), range(1000), 1000, np.sqrt(10000)))
```

Running time: 
%timeit pcreateobj(10000)

**10 loops, best of 3: 31.6 ms per loop**

C++ class code:

```
from libcpp.map cimport map as cpp_map
from libcpp.vector cimport vector as cpp_vector
from libcpp.list cimport list as cpp_list
from libc.math cimport sqrt
ctypedef cpp_map[int,cpp_list[int]] coordslind
ctypedef cpp_vector[double] objpp

cdef cppclass Obj:
    coordslind lind
    objpp pxlmead
    objpp pxlstd
    int pxlcnt
    int bandcnt
cpdef createobj(num):
    cdef Obj* obj
    cdef cpp_vector[Obj*] pool
    cdef int i
    for i in range(num):
        obj=new Obj()
        obj.lind[0]=range(1000)
        obj.pxlmead=range(1000)
        obj.pxlstd=range(1000)
        obj.pxlcnt=1000
        obj.bandcnt=<int>sqrt(10000)
        pool.push_back(obj)
```

Running time:
%timeit createobj(10000)

**1 loop, best of 3: 3.04 s per loop**

So how do I improve this code to get a speed similar to Python? Thank you

Comment: I find it very unlikely that creation of 10000 of such objects would take 3 seconds.

Comment: I'd guess the poor performance is in converting the Python lists from range into C++ types

Answer (score 0):

Cython can not provide a python `range` constructor for `std::vector` directly. It has to create the `range` buffer as a python object first and then convert/populate it to `std::vector`. (Basically call `__Pyx_PyObject_Call` and then `__pyx_convert_vector_from_py_double`). Hence, rewrite the `createobj` function this way:

```
cpdef createobjNEW(int num):
    cdef Obj* obj
    cdef cpp_vector[Obj*] pool
    pool.reserve(num)
    cdef int i, j, cnt = 1000

    for i in range(num):
        obj=new Obj()
        obj.pxlmead.reserve(cnt)
        obj.pxlstd.reserve(cnt)
        for j in range(cnt):
            obj.lind[0].push_back(j)
            obj.pxlmead.push_back(j)
            obj.pxlstd.push_back(j)
        obj.pxlcnt=cnt
        obj.bandcnt=<int>sqrt(10000)
        pool.push_back(obj)
```

### Timing:

On my machine with Python 2.7, with the above-mentioned changes I get

```
In[0]: %timeit pcreateobj(10000) # python version
1 loop, best of 3: 468 ms per loop
In[0]: %timeit createobj(10000) # original cython version
1 loop, best of 3: 3.74 s per loop
In[1]: %timeit createobjNEW(10000) # modified cython function
1 loop, best of 3: 1.07 s per loop
```

Note that the way you are creating `std::map` with `pair[int,cpp_list[int]]` in cython is not as optimal/lightweight as creating lists in python. You should instead use a vector:

```
ctypedef cpp_map[int,cpp_vector[int]] coordslind
```

With this change I get

```
In[2]: %timeit createobjNEW(10000) 
1 loop, best of 3: 257 ms per loop
```

At least speed-wise this gets you to the land of C++. Further optimisation/performance tuning to this function is C++ related and there is nothing much cython can do. For instance, you can stack allocate your `Obj` instance and have a `cpp_vector[Obj]` instead of `cpp_vectorpool[Obj*]`. In my machine that brings the timing of the function to almost half as much (**`114 ms`**).

Also note that in Python 3, `range`s are generators and do not create an actual list of values, whereas in C++ you are creating the vectors manually.

Comment: Thanks you. I follow your code and  get a running time of 133ms on my own machine, but after changing vector[Obj *] pool to vercor[Obj] pool, the running time becomes 169ms.  This may be result from pool.push_back(obj[0])
. If I use cdef Obj obj, the ipython reminds me of bad allocation.